# Angular won't open large blob file

Tags: angular, pdf, url, blob

I am generating a pdf file on the backend and returning it to the frontend as stream buffer

[image]

For small PDF's everything works fine - a new browser tab opens and I can download the generated pdf. However I encounter a problem when I generate large PDFs, the server request is completed and I can see the blob data but it doesn't open the PDF in a new tab so I can see and download the generated PDF.

component.ts

```
async createReport() {
    let blob = await this.searchService.createReport(this.searchService.submitObj);
    let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    window.open(fileURL);
}
```

service.ts

```
async createReport(data) {
    let pdfStream = await this.http.post<any>(
      environment.apiUrl + 'search/create-issues-report',
      data,
      { responseType: 'blob' as 'json'}
    ).toPromise();

    return new Blob([pdfStream], { type: 'application/pdf' });
}
```

Are there other settings I need to make before opening large pdf files?

Answer (score 0):

Nvmind it seems Chrome blocked popups coming from localhost:4200 and prevented the window open event